# Delete question with upvoted answer

Tags: support, reputation, rules

Suppose someone answers a question and get some up vote in that answer. Now the OP decides to delete his/her question. What will happen to the answer and the reputation gained from the answer? Will it be gone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't delete a question that has an upvoted answer.

Says: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

PS: I purposely didn't quote all rules for deleting questions. Better to have a single source, I think.

Comment: Don't know how I skipped that. Thank you. Same rule for meta?

Comment: I don't know. You can try with this one. :) It will cost me 20 meta points, but that's okay. ;) The post I linked to is on StackExchange Meta, so I guess it applies to the entire network.

Comment: I see. lose lose situation then.

Comment: In what sense? *Nothing*, really **nothing** about Stack Overflow bugs me more than answering a question and then have it deleted by way of thanks. This happened so often to me, I now make a point of up-voting *reasonable* answers just to prevent it. (When a better answer appears, I take that vote back 'n vote on the other.)

Comment: @Jongware I know the feeling. But still, (even though this is a bit off-topic), if the answer was good enough to upvote, you don't have to take back the vote. And if it wasn't then it's not so bad if it's deleted either.

Comment: @GolezTrol: you're correct, I take that part back. In hindsight I don't believe I ever actually did so (unless fully justified, that is, comments convinced me that I was wrong to up-vote in the first place).

Comment: @salmanwahed yes same rule for meta.

Comment: @Jongware This thing happened to me also. Question was deleted after answering it. In my opinion this activity is a lose lose situation both for OP as well as the answerer.

Comment: And that's why you can't delete a question if it had more than one answer or an upvoted answer. OP will have just a little bit of freedom to delete a question if it only has one answer and that answer doesn't have any upvotes. It has happened to me that I was writing an answer and the question got deleted by the time I was finished. This is frustrating too, but what are you gonna do? If answering would prevent deletion right away, people would make a quick place holder answer while writing a larger one, and that would be counter effective too.