# Why are questions with so many downvotes not deleted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I've recently seen some [heavily down-voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068763/forcing-a-function-to-return-if-false) on the Stack Overflow network and I was wondering why none of these have been deleted or closed by moderators. These questions have no need to be kept as they are just wasting precious space on Stack Overflow's servers.

**Edit:**

A better example of a question which should be deleted is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866043/php-error-500-but-cannot-find-mistakes) (which has now been deleted).

Comment: Because they have good answers.....Pigs find truffles!

Comment: Probably because of a certain sentence in the question in the first revision. I also think there was a meta post about it, so plus or multiplied by meta effect and since you asked another meta question it will soon be: pow(votes, meta effect)

Comment: 42, (!) votes for answering 'use a loop'.  Brilliant.

Comment: It is a top Google hit for "forcing false return" and has 49 helpful votes.  Should we break the Internet?  Erm ... probably.

Comment: Note that this question also has 49 upvotes, which means that about 1/5 of users who voted think that this question is useful.

Comment: Objection: since the accepted answer now tallies a `42` score, the question should stay. More seriously, it could be used as a dupe target for other questions of its kin down the way.

Comment: But how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866043/php-error-500-but-cannot-find-mistakes ? This is down-voted 22 times yet the answer has only received 4 up-votes! There is no reason why this post shouldn't be deleted

Comment: This problem won't go away as long as people keep answering OT questions and getting upvotes for what tends to be chatty guesswork, aka crystal ball debugging. Unfortunately, I certainly don't see that happening.

Comment: @RowanHarley Questions with upvoted answers can be closed, but [not deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295706/delete-question-with-upvoted-answer).

Comment: @user3386109 10K and 20K user certainly can delete a question that has upvoted answers.  It is just the OP cannot unilaterally delete it if it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver but they can vote to delete (if I recall correctly).

Comment: @BaummitAugen: There's an [effort to remove the badge most commonly used to defend not downvoting those answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279285/can-we-retire-the-reversal-badge/), which you may be interested in.

Comment: @user3386109 The author of the question can't delete it themselves when it has an upvoted answer, and it won't be automatically deleted by the roomba if is has an upvoted answer, but a mod or 10k users can still delete it.

Comment: It'd be hilarious if this question got downvoted to hell too.

Comment: FWIW, disk space isn't a consideration here, since deleted posts are not actually removed from the servers. They are still visible to users with rep >= 10k, diamond moderators, and Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: Why does bluefeet keep undeleting the first reference question?

Comment: @Rizier123 I think that [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240427/271772) is the one that you're referring to.

Comment: @Martin Probably because it is a useful question with a useful answer set. It's got tons of downvotes most likely due to others thinking it's a dumb/obvious question. The close reason also seems incorrect. But that's neither here nor there; I've flagged the question for moderator attention so that it can be considered for historical lock.

Comment: IMO deleting these questions is pointless and counter productive.  Stack is designed to help people. Not just professional programmers but those who are learning. If we delete questions just because people think they aren't good questions we end up losing the entire point of the site. I don't know how many times I've been saved hours from an answer on a downvoted question. By deleting these questions your only going to see more of the same question being asked. Don't be a loser. Stay true to the point of the site and DO NOT DELETE questions that may be helpful

Comment: Compared to most questions I come across, it's also heavily upvoted with 58 upvotes as of right now.

Comment: "this" has been deleted.

Comment: And that's the problem with linking examples of questions that should be deleted...

Comment: I think a procedure should be established to prevent "gang bangs" of downvoting for new users. My account may now have nearly 16k points on stackoverflow, but before that it was banned for 6 months after a couple noob questions sent my account into disgrace

Comment: I oppose to close the question just because it has so "many" downvotes, consider if you have some mind like "already enough downvotes", it is possibly rating the score of the post, instead of the quality of the post

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason is that the proposal in [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077) has not been implemented yet. It would take care of many of the questions you refer to:

> **If a question is more than 30 days old**, and...
>
> - has a score of -1 or less, with no votes in the past 30 days
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - is not locked
>
> ...it will be automatically deleted.

Unfortunately, this is still just a proposal, soon to be two years old.

As an aside, the server space is not saved by deletion, since all deleted posts remain in the database. In fact, deletion uses more space, since it has to be recorded as an event in PostHistory table.

Comment: The example question had an answer with a score well in excess of 0, so would not have been deleted.

Comment: a) Do you know why the deleted posts still remain in the DB? b) Do they ever actually get deleted? Under _any_ circumstances?

Comment: @Arc676 Deleted posts are still visible to high reputation users. I suspect the main reason for retaining deleted posts online is for auditing purposes (consider if someone were to be defamed in a post - if this was needed for a court case later on, it's a lot easier if the deleted content is available, rather than having to find just the right backup set; Disks are cheaper than people's time in that scenario)

Comment: @Arc676 There are special cases where the SE developers can (and have) gone in and purged the database of a question or answer. It's rare, and there's usually a good reason behind it.

Comment: The first question referenced wouldn't be caught by the new criteria since it has multiple positive-score answers.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Questions more than 30 days old that are downvoted, have no answers, and are not locked [are automatically deleted by the system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/135615), and have been for a while. The suggestions you link to were implemented a long while ago. They would not apply to the questions being discussed here, because these questions have upvoted answers and would not be deleted by the system.

Comment: @BradLarson But the suggestion in this answer would also include questions that have answers (with 0 or negative score).

Answer (score 6):

I'd give it two reasons:

1. The **answers** may be good, as written in length in a **Stack Exchange article**, questions are sand, and good answers are pearls, the goal being the **pearls**.
2. It may prevent such questions from being asked **repeatedly**, and push newbies to learn more about what content is wanted on **SE**.

Comment: SE is a punishing place for newbies, and I mean that in every construable way. If you don't like something, at least do somebody the courtesy of telling them why you downvoted their answer. It's not a rule, but it proves you weren't just being a drive-by jerk. And as to the pearls, if we're just trawling the sand for good answers, why even make a question votable? Why bother to implement a system where you can say a question corresponding to a good answer is a good one?

Comment: I always try to comment when DVing, but at times it's clear the other side needs to read some FAQs. Questions should be vocable because I don't want to waste my time reading a poorly asked question. @CalebWoodman

Comment: In this specific case, the answers aren't particularly good.

Comment: @Lundin it's still a program that removes them.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the technical quality of this specific example:

- The question is essentially beginner-level code begging - how do I write loops, or if you will: "please tell me how to do utterly fundamental things so I don't have to study". It should have been closed from the start. However, bad as the question might be, there's really no point in continuing some nasty bandwagon down-voting past -10.
- The accepted answer is essentially "here is some fish, please come back for more". It reveals nothing that was not already known by enthusiast or professional C programmers.

  There is nothing in that answer that merits all those up-votes, particularly since it uses unconventional, poor style and also repeats the check twice, which is never good. A more elegant solution worthy of some up-votes would have been something along the lines of:

  ```
  kk=0;
  while(kk < 12)
  {
    // ...
  }
  ```

  I suspect the up-votes are the result of some "meta-effect", where people with little or no experience from C programming decided to cast votes.
- The first part of the answer by zwol (that answers the question) is a bit obscure but answers the question. No real reason to neither up-vote nor down-vote in my opinion. The second part regarding how to do a binary search is "good stuff" but not really related to the question. It would be a great answer *to a different question*.

The only thing worth preserving here is the second part of the answer by zwol, but it is out of context for the given question. So I would recommend to delete the whole post with a bit of "collateral damage" as result.

Comment: according to current voting guideline I know, I don't think there is something like "already have enough downvotes", since the vote decision should be determined by the content of the post, not the current score of the post

Answer (score 5):

> I've recently seen some heavily down-voted questions on the stack overflow network and I was wondering, why have none of these been deleted or closed by moderators.

Possible reasons:

- looking at each post below a given threshold in order to review is boring, nobody wants to do that
- moderators have more important things to do: check flagged posts, remove spam, etc.
- this post has been forgotten since it received all these downvotes and nobody cared

> These questions have no need to be kept as they are just wasting precious space on stack overflow's servers.

Space is not precious (see [Hardware is cheap](http://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/)), the price of data storage is decreasing each year. Even if space was precious, it would be a problem for Stack Overflow, not the community. The community do its best to increase the global quality of the questions and answers, the space used by posts is irrelevant.

In other words, if a question is bad, it should be removed only because it's bad, not because it uses space (that's also the case for every content).