# Why don't we just delete such a bad questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, deleted-questions

Why do we keep such a bad questions there?

Like:

- [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905734/982161)
- [Forcing a function to return if false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21068763/982161)

I mean a bad question is not getting better even after a great answer...

Those must be deleted, IMHO.

Comment: Well, if nothing else, it gives somethng to link to in the case of future questions from the malware/spam kiddies, those unable to program computers, and other such VLQ rubbish.

Comment: Related: ["Why are questions with so many downvotes not deleted?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323042/why-are-questions-with-so-many-downvotes-not-deleted), which actually was the reason why I locked the second question. There was a delete / undelete war going on because some thought it should be deleted and some not. It also had received three "rude or abusive" flags in an attempt to destroy it. That all has passed, and I forgot to unlock it afterward, so I've done that now.

Comment: Now the second question is deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I mean a bad question is not getting better even after a great answer...

I disagree wholeheartedly. A great answer can absolutely redeem a poor question. They both live on the same page, and a great answer can make that page worth keeping around. That's the whole reason the [Reversal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) exists.

(In addition to that, I'm not sure the "100,000 emails" got that many downvotes because of particularly low quality. It's entirely possible that people downvoted it because... ewww, spam.)

Comment: That's true enough for the first example, but the second example is just someone asking for people to do their homework and people doing the homework.  There's no value there.  It's not like that's the only place on the internet with the information "write a loop if you want your code to loop", so it being deleted isn't losing the internet anything.

Comment: @Servy Agreed, but the question appears to be more about highly-downvoted questions in general than about these two specific examples.

Comment: And my point is that the *vast* majority of answered bad questions don't actually have valuable answers, sure you've got the super rare exception, like the email example, but it's *very* difficult for an answer to actually overcome major problems with the question, and even if it can, it being on a bad question *greatly* reduces its value.  If the information in the answer really is that good, odds are it'd be much better to post that same information under a much better question (perhaps a self-answered question by the author) that doesn't have those problems.

Comment: @Servy Really, that was the point you were trying to make? Because you were only talking about one specific question in your other comment. Maybe you should just post an answer.